# Which folders in a Blazor WASM project have "meaning"?

Tags: blazor

The default template for a Blazor WASM project organizes files into several folders.

- Blazor.csproj

  - wwwroot
  - Pages (contains routable components)
  - Shared (shared components)

I know wwwroot is used to server up static content, Shared appears to be for shared components and Pages for routable pages.  But while in a Razor pages project the structure under "Pages" describes the routes, Blazor requires an explicit @page directive.

My question is, does this mean I can organize my Blazor project anyway I wish for pages and components?  Or do they need to be in specific folders, such as Pages and Shared?

Kep

Comment: I highly recommend Chris Sainty's forthcoming book. Some of it is available now. He discusses a "features" organization where you have routable pages and related components in the same folder. The routable pages would have a Page suffix (FooPage). Then you can have a folder level _Imports so you don't need a bunch more using statements. https://chrissainty.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does this mean I can organize my Blazor project anyway I wish for pages and components?

Yes.

Do note that `_Imports.razor` has a line for `@using MyApp.Client.Shared` so that the components there can be found. But that follows the normal rules for C# namespaces, in a razor syntax.

You can even use the full name as in `<MyApp.Client.MyComponents.SomeComponent />`